# My HTML Based OS' Apps Flicker between dark and light when Dark Mode is on

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a website called JazzyOS that is an operating system made out of HTML. https://jazzyos.awesomecrater.repl.co/
I started to add a dark mode (not in settings) that can be activated by this code in the JavaScript console:

```
dark = true
```

But in all the apps that have it embedded, the dark mode keeps flickering on and off if it is turned on. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Can you include the code that you suspect you may be causing the problem?

Comment: That's hilarious, btw. Good job getting it up and running.

Comment: The code that is in some of the apps is:
setInterval(function () {
    var d = document.querySelector('.dmyi');
    if(parent.dark&& d.innerHTML !== '<link rel="stylesheet" href="darkca.css">') {
      d.innerHTML = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="darkca.css" />';
    } else {
      d.innerHTML = "";
    }
  }, 500);

Comment: The main page has similar code but doesn't have the flashing problem

Comment: thx for the compliment

Comment: Check out css custom properties. You should be able to set them once on body, then have them apply across the entire page. For an example, check out stack overflow's dark mode settings and how they are applied in the developer console.

Comment: button {
  background-color: #464444;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #575757;
}
body {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that there is something wrong with the if-then statement.
It is like this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var d = document.querySelector('.dmyi');
    if(parent.dark&& d.innerHTML !== '<link rel="stylesheet" href="darkca.css">') {
      d.innerHTML = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="darkca.css" />';
    } else {
      d.innerHTML = "";
    }
  }, 500);
```

But it should be like this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    var d = document.querySelector('.dmyi');
    if(parent.dark) {
      if(d.innerHTML !== '<link rel="stylesheet" href="darkca.css">') {
         d.innerHTML = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="darkca.css" />';
      }
    } else {
      d.innerHTML = "";
    }
  }, 500);
```